# Convert character sequence to special character

Tags: javascript, json

I have a rather large string containing several escaped characters (think \n, \xB7, ...). These 'special characters' are stored in the string as a character sequence, not the actual special characters. In short, I need a way to convert a character sequence to the actual special character they represent.

Here are some examples I created so far:

```
var seq = "\n"
//outputs "
//         "

seq = "\\n" 
// outputs "\n"

seq.replace(/\\\\/g, "\\") 
// outputs "\n"
```

I need to replace all character sequences, not just \n:

```
var seq = "\\n"
seq.replace(/\\\\n/g, "\n") 
// outputs "
//          "
```

Comment: That's somewhat confusing, the first `"\"` isn't part of your string when typing string literals, it's escaping only.

Comment: Would you share your actual sequence? You need the appropriate regex to match those probably.

Comment: The actual sequence is a string I get from Elasticsearch (containing mails). All special characters in these mails are formatted as a sequence of characters: `\ ` + `n` in stead of `\n` or `\ ` + `x` + `B` + `7` in stead of `\xB7`. `\xB7` is 1 character, whereas `\ ` + `x` + `B` + `7` are 4 characters.

Comment: Also, `JSON.parse(<sequence>)`, doesn't work since the parse is happening in Elasticsearch on a string that already includes these character sequences.

Comment: @adeneo: That would be the ideal case indeed. but `\ ` is a character on its own as is. In languages like Python, you could convert it to a raw String and turn it back which would yield the escaped characters. When converting these strings in javascript (`String.raw\`<sequence>\``), I have no clue on how to turn them back to a regular string.